# How to make each individual bar in a bar chart have the same starting point

Tags: ios, swiftui, bar-chart

I'm creating a very simple bar chart by using SwiftUI's [`Rectangle`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftuis-built-in-shapes).

When created, the bars align themselves to the center of the screen, therefore they end up not having the same starting point, like below:

[image]

How do I modify my code so that the bar marked as 14-09-2021 can be on the same line as the rest?

Here's the code I use to create these individual bar charts:

```
        VStack {
        Spacer()
        Text(history.target)
        Rectangle()
            .fill(trackingViewModel.starColor(stars: history.target))
            .frame(width: 70, height: trackingViewModel.barHeight(stars: history.target))
        Text(history.date)
        Spacer()
    }
```

And then I use `ForEach` to create the barchart:

```
        HStack {
        ForEach(trackingViewModel.trackingHistory, id: \.self) { history in
            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                IndividualHistoryBar(history: history, trackingViewModel: trackingViewModel)
            }
                
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I call this history chart view by using a sheet. I tried `Asperi`'s solution by adding `.alignment` to the HStack, but that didn't do anything. Could this be the reason? Does the sheet automatically align everything to the center?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set alignment

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {    // << here !!
   ForEach(trackingViewModel.trackingHistory, id: \.self) { history in
```

Comment: Hi! I added the alignment but I don't see any difference in the result. :(

Comment: You also need to remove the spacer from the bottom of your VStack

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! The trick was to use `alignment .lastTextBaseline`, which takes the date as the baseline and aligns everything accordingly.

End result:

[image]

Modified code:

```
    HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) { // <-- here!
        ForEach(trackingViewModel.trackingHistory, id: \.self) { history in
            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                IndividualHistoryBar(history: history, trackingViewModel: trackingViewModel)
            }                   
        }
    }
```